# rails console no method each for model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why should this happen:

```
Sms.each do |sms|
  sms.time_stamp=Time.at(sms.time_stamp_long/1000)
  sms.save
end
```

> undefined method `each' for Sms:Class (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use [find_each](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each)

```rb
Sms.find_each do |sms|
  sms.update_columns(time_stamp: Time.at(sms.time_stamp_long / 1000)
end
```

Comment: For some reason when I try to set the value of a mysql datetime column to a ruby datetime value it sets the value to 1970-01-01 but if I print out the datetime values instead of saving to the database then they print out their actual dates

Comment: mechnicov: you forgot to_i for time_stamp_long and if i add it myself then it will try to update time_stamp to 1970-01-01

Comment: I didn't forget `to_i`. I just took code from your question. Probably *you* forgot it

Answer (score 0):

What you really should be doing here is fixing the regrettable descision that lead you to store EPOCH instead of actual date/time types in the first place with minimal involvement from Rails.

MYSQL has the [FROM_UNIXTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function that takes EPOCH time as input and outputs a date. Use this in a single query which will update all the rows:

```
Sms.update_all(
  'time_stamp = FROM_UNIXTIME(time_stamp_long)'
).where(time_stamp: nil)
```

This will be an faster then pulling each record out of the database and then creating a UPDATE query for each row by an order of magnitude.

Once you're done drop the `time_stamp_long` column.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what kind of garbage you have stored (for example why do you think you should be doing `/1000` on an epoch puzzles me) and you might have to add additional type casts. The general approach is correct though.

Comment: Here's one of the values of time_stamp_long and here's what happens when I try to run from_unixtime on it in mysql: ```mysql> select from_unixtime(1663681609392);
+------------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1663681609392) |
+------------------------------+
| NULL                         |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Ah, its not actually an epoch. It's miliseconds. If you do `select from_unixtime(1663681609392/1000)` you'll get `2022-09-20 13:46:49.3920`. I don't know why they thought it was a good idea to just return null instead of raising an error when the values are out of bounds. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2HSBRyWEHAdqVWwiEWUqez/1